# Why does my MaterialUI Select dropdown render as a row?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use the `[<Select>][1]` component from MaterialUI. For some reason, all of the options render in a row, rather than one row per option.

[image]

I can't figure out what would be causing it. When I inspect the actual HTML elements rendered for this component (see below), I can see that there is a `<ul>` in here which actually constitutes the list of options. I noticed that when I adjust the style in the console as follows, the options now render each on their own row (though the location is a bit off):

```
element.style {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

[image: Correct, almost]

Here is the code for the component I'm rendering this in:

```
import { FormControl, InputLabel, MenuItem, Select } from "@mui/material";
import { useGetPriorityOptionsQuery } from "generated/graphql";
import { selectPriorityItemIds, setSelectedPriorityItemIds } from "Redux/callCenterSchedulingReducer";
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "Redux/hooks";

export default function PrioritySelector() {
    const { data } = useGetPriorityOptionsQuery();
    const options = data?.priorityOptions ?? [];

    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    const selectedPriorityItemIds = useAppSelector(selectPriorityItemIds);

    return (
        <FormControl className="w-13r whitespace-no-wrap">
            <InputLabel>Priority</InputLabel>
            <Select
                multiple
                value={selectedPriorityItemIds}
                onChange={(e) => dispatch(setSelectedPriorityItemIds(e.target.value as number[]))}
            >
                {options.map(opt => <MenuItem key={`priority-${opt.id}`} value={opt.id}>{opt.text}</MenuItem>)}
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
    )
}
```

So, what could be causing this, and what could I try to rectify this?

Here is the actual HTML rendered for the drop down menu.
[image: Actual HTML rendered for drop down]

Comment: you are using the "multiple" example for your Select

Comment: @darrenz yes, I did reference that example. I don't quite understand what your point is. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @BlakeF. Please provide a code sandbox reproducing your issue. This isn't the default behavior of `Select` so there must be some CSS that you are including that has this effect.